# mysqli_free_result(), Returning A Warning

Tags: php, oop, mysqli, warnings

The following method does its job but keeps printing a warning also, im pretty new to OOP so i would like to know why exactly.

I have done some Googling and it seems likes its me mixing procedural with OOP which is giving the warning, well from the replies i have read elsewhere at least.

The code:

```
function __construct(){
    global $connection;

    $mysqli_result=$connection->query("select module from modules");
    while($row=$mysqli_result->fetch_row()){
        $this->whitelist[]=$row[0];
    }
    mysqli_free_result($row);
    return;
}
```

The warning:

```
mysqli_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in.....
```

I would appreciate someone shedding some light on this if possible.

Comment: $row isn't the result, $mysqli_result is the result

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `MySQLi` in an object oriented fashion, <strike>and you cannot use the procedural functions with it</strike> <sup>incorrect, see edit</sup>. You would do:

```
$mysqli_result->free()
```

...instead.

Even if you were using the procedural approach, what you have done is incorrect because `fetch_row()` returns an array, and `mysqli_free_result()` would expect the result resource - you would need to do:

```
mysqli_free_result($mysqli_result);
```

...but for your code, the first example is what you want.

**EDIT**

Actually, after testing, you can in fact use the second option as well. But still, the first option is the best fit for your code.